# Add multiple items to an array

Tags: java, arrays

So lets say I want to make an array of nine country names. I have the code to create the array:

```
String[] countryName = new String[9];
```

Lets say I wanted to add nine unique country names to this array. I could do something like this:

```
countryName[0] = "Mexico";
countryName[1] = "United States";
```

and so on. But is there a way I could add all of the names at once? Maybe something like an add() statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare an array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array-in-java)

Comment: You can just use `String[] countryName = { "Mexico", "United States", ... };`. I would strongly advise reading a good Java book for this sort of thing though - it's a much more efficient way of learning the basics of a language than asking specific questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can initialize the array with:

```
String[] countryName = new String[]{"Mexico", "Italy", "Spain"};
```

Comment: and how is it different from what Jon Skeet has advised?

Comment: @Shail016 by being an answer and not a comment, probably.

Comment: well I just observed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write simple utility method using `varargs`

```
static void addAll(String[] arr, String ... elements)
{
   if (elements != null)
   {
      System.arraycopy(elements, 0, arr, 0, elements.length);
   }
}
```

Usage

```
addAll(countryName, "Mexico", "US", "Ukraine");
```

Answer (score 0):

Enlist all contries in `String` and use `split`

```
   String str="Country1,Country2,Country3";
   String array[]=str.split(",");//You even don't need to initialize array
```

*Use delimeter carefully to avoid extra spaces.*

---

*NOTE:
As this is one of the ways to add values to array but still I suggest you to go for `Michel Foucault`'s answer as `split` will have more overhead than direct initialization.*

Comment: I like me your solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayList this has the Add method.

```
ArrayList<String> countryName = new ArrayList<String>();
countryName.add("Mexico");
countryName.add("United States");
countryName.add("Dominican Republic");
countryName.add("...");
```

Comment: for this one can also do `Arrays.asList("country1", "country2");`